# Error installing greek inputenc

Tags: babel, babel-greek

I'm trying to use Greek text with babel package. When trying to install it, a message pops up: "Unfortunately, the package greek-inputenc could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\feder\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log".  How can I fix this? Screenshot attached. Notice that I use \RequirePackage because the file is a .sty. [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It seems you were compiling at the same time. Try to install it directly from MiKTeX package manager.

Comment: the miktex server seems to be out-of sync currently. You will have to wait a day or install through a local repository.